# Is there a way to create an awk input inactivity timer?

Tags: awk

I have a text source (a log file), which gets new lines appended to it by some third party.

I can output the additions to my source file using `tail -f source`. I can then pipe that through an awk script `awk -f parser.awk` to parse and format the output.

My question is: while `tail -f source | awk -f parser.awk` is running, is there a way to call `function foo()` inside my `parser.awk` script every time there is more than 5 seconds elapsed without anything coming through the pipe into the standard input of the awk script?

*Edit: Currently using GNU Awk 3.1.6. May be able to upgrade to newer version if required.*

Comment: best to update your question with the output of `awk --version`. That said, it's not likely you can solve this problem with awk. Good luck.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Read-Timeout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shell's `read` supports `-t` and `-u`, here's an ugly hack:

```
{ echo hello; sleep 6; echo world; } | awk 'BEGIN{ 
    while( "while read -t 5 -u 3 line; do echo \"$line\"; done" | getline > 0 )
        print
    }' 3<&0
```

You can replace the `print` in the body of the while loop with your script.  However, it would probably make a lot more sense to put the read timeout between tail and awk in the pipeline, and it would make even more sense to re-implement tail to timeout.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and it says "hello". Now I don't want to stop on time out, just print, say "5 sec", and keep going. So the expected output is "hello \n 5 sec \n world". Therefore I tried `BEGIN{ while(1) { <your original while block> ; print "5 sec"}}`. But that does not block on the `while read -t` the second dime it gets there, and I get "5 sec" outputs in a tight loop. Can you help me out on what I have missed? I'm not overly familiar with everything here.

Comment: You could do `while :; do read -t 5 -u 3 line && echo \"$line\" || echo timeout; done`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer to your question. However there is a little hack in shell that can do practically what you want:

```
{ tail -f log.file >&2 |  { while : ; do sleep 5; echo SECRET_PHRASE ; done ; } ; } 2>&1 | awk -f script.awk
```

When awk receives SECRET_PHRASE it will run `foo` function every 5 seconds. Unfortunately is will run it every 5 second even in case there was some output during this time from tail.

ps. You can replace '{}' with '()' and vice versa. In the first case it won't create subshell, in the second one it will.

The another way is to append this secret phrase dirctly to log file in case nobody wrote there during last five seconds. But looks like it's not good idea due to you will have spoiled log file.